# Why finish() make all the activities can't go back to previous activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm new in Android Java and I have some question about the intent. This is the intent concept of the app

[image]

First, The ***Launch Activity*** have two button to let the user push the screen to ***Register Activity*** and ***Login Activity*** . Other than that, User also can press the back button to go back the ***Launch Activity***. So it is not include `finish()`.

```
//Login Activity
Intent i = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
LaunchActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

In the AndroidManifest, Main Activity (yellow) is the first activity.

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

On ***Main Activity***, I will check if whether the user is login to the app or not. If haven't login, I will push the screen to ***Launch Acitivty*** by using this code. (I'm using this code on the sign out button too)

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LaunchActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

So I use `finish()` to prevent the user go back to the ***Main Activity***.

But the problem is the `finish()` also let the ***Login and Register Activity*** can't go back to the ***Launch Activity***.

So is the `finish()` make all the activities can't go back to previous activity? why and how to fix it?

Due to the comments, I know the problem is the flag. So I removed those flags when checking the login status and sign out. but after I login successfully (login screen to main screen), I can press the back button to go back to the launch screen on the main screen. why? It only happen when first login. after I relaunch the app, the app work fine. This is the code I use on the login button.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Is it because we can't destroy the launch screen on the login screen? but adding those flags should be destroy all the history right?

Comment: it is not finish(). Why are you using those flags?

Comment: The problem is with the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`. Adding this flag will not add your LauncherActivity to the stack and hence when you click back on the Login/Register activity you don't see the launcher activity

Comment: I removed those flags when checking the login and sign out. It works but after I login successfully (login screen -> main screen). I can press the back button to go back the launch screen. why? It only happen when first login. after I relaunch the app, the app work fine. @AlimParkar

Comment: After a successful login, you would need to finish the login activity as well. This would remove it from the stack.

Comment: ya, I added flags and finish() on the click listener of the login button.